# Query for the next day with more therms

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi i have a problem i need to know if the next day is a holiday.
I have set up a temptable(Will become a table later) that i need becouse i might add other freedays.

Problem line

```
Holiday Datum   (No column name)
0   2016-02-05  2016-02-05
```

This should be, becouse the next day have a 1 as holiday, cant figure this out. I know it check next day and if the 1 is the "current day"

```
Holiday Datum   (No column name)
0   2016-02-05  2016-02-08
```

*EXECUTABLE*

```
DECLARE @start DATE
SET @start = '2016-02-01'

DECLARE @end DATE
SET @end = '2016-02-10'

WHILE(@start<=@end)
BEGIN

DECLARE  @Holiday TABLE (Datum DATE,Holiday bit)
INSERT INTO @Holiday 

SELECT 
@start, 
(SELECT CASE 
WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@start) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS Holiday
SET @start = DATEADD(d,1,@start)
END

SELECT * FROM @Holiday

SELECT h.Holiday,h.Datum,
(SELECT
 CASE  

  WHEN DATEADD(d,1,h.Datum) = DATEADD(d,1,h.Datum) AND h.Holiday = 1
  THEN (SELECT TOP 1 Datum FROM @Holiday WHERE Datum > h.Datum AND Holiday = 0 )

  ELSE h.Datum
  END)

FROM @Holiday h
```

Comment: the problem is that `WHEN DATEADD(d,1,h.Datum) = DATEADD(d,1,h.Datum) AND h.Holiday = 1`  is not checking if the next date (record) is a holiday. Its only checking if the current row is a holiday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1:**

Since you are generating values for the `@Holiday` table and they are sorted, you can join and sort the two tables to look at the next day as follows:

```
SELECT t.h1Datum AS Datum ,
       t.Holiday ,
       t.IsNextDayAHoliday FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY h1.Datum ORDER BY h1.Datum ASC) Nr,
    h1.Datum h1Datum, h1.Holiday Holiday, h2.Holiday IsNextDayAHoliday
    FROM @Holiday h1 LEFT JOIN @Holiday h2 ON  h1.Datum < h2.Datum
) t WHERE nr = 1
```

The result is this:

```
Datum   Holiday IsNextDayAHoliday
2016-02-01  0   0
2016-02-02  0   0
2016-02-03  0   0
2016-02-04  0   0
2016-02-05  0   1
2016-02-06  1   1
2016-02-07  1   0
2016-02-08  0   0
2016-02-09  0   0
2016-02-10  0   NULL
```

As you will see the last day is null because it is not contained in the `@Holiday` table.

**Approach 2:**

Another approach is to `CROSS APPLY` the function that calculates what a holiday is:

```
SELECT Datum ,
       Holiday,
       IsHolidayCalc.IsNextDayAHoliday
FROM @Holiday
CROSS APPLY (SELECT IIF(DATENAME(WEEKDAY, DATEADD(DAY, 1, Datum)) IN ('Saturday','Sunday'), 1, 0) IsNextDayHoliday) IsHolidayCalc
```

And the result now has no NULLs to deal with:

```
Datum   Holiday IsNextDayHoliday
2016-02-01  0   0
2016-02-02  0   0
2016-02-03  0   0
2016-02-04  0   0
2016-02-05  0   1
2016-02-06  1   1
2016-02-07  1   0
2016-02-08  0   0
2016-02-09  0   0
2016-02-10  0   0
```

Comment: +1 Thanks
Is it just to copy this into the current code

Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 46
Invalid column name 'IsNextDayAHoliday'.

Comment: did you find the problem? what version of sql server are you running?

Answer (score 1):

Although Candide approaches are valid, it does not provide you with the next date that is a free day. Below is a recursive query that will provide the next free date. I believe this is what you are looking for.

run this code block:

```
DECLARE @start DATE
SET @start = '2016-02-01'

DECLARE @end DATE
SET @end = '2016-02-10'

WHILE(@start<=@end)
BEGIN

DECLARE  @Holiday TABLE (Datum DATE,Holiday bit)
INSERT INTO @Holiday 

SELECT 
@start, 
(SELECT CASE 
WHEN DATENAME(WEEKDAY,@start) IN ('Saturday','Sunday')
THEN 1
ELSE 0
END) AS Holiday
SET @start = DATEADD(d,1,@start)
END;

WITH Holiday_CTE (holiday, datum, free_date) AS (
select top 1 h.Holiday, 
h.Datum,
 CASE  
  WHEN h2.Holiday = 1  OR  h.Holiday = 1
  THEN (Select Datum from (SELECT b.Datum, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Datum asc) AS INT) AS rownum FROM @Holiday b WHERE b.Datum > h.Datum AND b.Holiday = 0) a where a.rownum=1 )
  ELSE h.Datum
  END as free_date
from @Holiday h 
inner join @Holiday h2 on h.Datum = DATEADD(d,1,h2.Datum)
order by h.Datum desc 
union all
SELECT
 h.Holiday,
 h.Datum, 
 CASE  
  WHEN hcte.Holiday = 1  OR  h.Holiday = 1
  THEN (Select Datum from (SELECT b.Datum, CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Datum asc) AS INT) AS rownum FROM @Holiday b WHERE b.Datum > h.Datum AND b.Holiday = 0) a where a.rownum=1 )
  ELSE h.Datum
  END as free_date
  FROM @Holiday h 
  inner join Holiday_CTE hcte on h.Datum = DATEADD(d,-1,hcte.Datum)
)
select * from
Holiday_CTE order by datum asc
```

Output:

```
holiday_ind |    Datum    | free_day
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
0           | 2016-02-01  | 2016-02-01
0           | 2016-02-02  | 2016-02-02
0           | 2016-02-03  | 2016-02-03
0           | 2016-02-04  | 2016-02-04 
0           | 2016-02-05  | 2016-02-08
1           | 2016-02-06  | 2016-02-08 
1           | 2016-02-07  | 2016-02-08
0           | 2016-02-08  | 2016-02-08
0           | 2016-02-09  | 2016-02-09
0           | 2016-02-10  | 2016-02-10
```

Please accept this as the answer if it provided you with what you were asking for.

Comment: patelb 
If its not a holiday the next day it sould give the same day.
Otherwise its nice graphical solution

holiday_ind |    Datum    | next_free_day
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
0           | 2016-02-01  | 2016-02-01
0           | 2016-02-02  | 2016-02-02
0           | 2016-02-03  | 2016-02-03
0           | 2016-02-04  | 2016-02-04 
0           | 2016-02-05  | 2016-02-08
1           | 2016-02-06  | 2016-02-08 
1           | 2016-02-07  | 2016-02-08
0           | 2016-02-08  | 2016-02-08
0           | 2016-02-09  | 2016-02-09
0           | 2016-02-10  | 2016-02-10

Comment: I made the edit. It will give the same day if the next day is not a holiday.

Comment: Awsome you and Candide ar saviors